# How to update a value, given a key in a hashmap?

Tags: java, key, hashmap

Suppose we have a `HashMap<String, Integer>` in Java.

How do I update (increment) the integer-value of the string-key for each existence of the string I find?

One could remove and reenter the pair, but overhead would be a concern.
Another way would be to just put the new pair and the old one would be replaced.

In the latter case, what happens if there is a hashcode collision with a new key I am trying to insert? The correct behavior for a hashtable would be to assign a different place for it, or make a list out of it in the current bucket.

Answer (score 1218, accepted):

```
map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
```

should be fine.  It will update the value for the existing mapping.  Note that this uses auto-boxing. With the help of `map.get(key)` we get the value of corresponding key, then you can update with your requirement. Here I am updating to increment value by 1.

Comment: In fact that is the most robust and scalable enterprise solution.

Comment: @Lavir, its not a bad solution, but dont see hows its the most robust and scalable.  An atomicinteger instead is much more scalable.

Comment: this assumes the key exists, right? I'm getting nullPointer Exception when it doesn't.

Comment: @Ian, yes, the key must exist.  However, a check can be added for this.

Comment: With Java 8, this can easily be avoided by using `getOrDefault`, for example: `map.put(key, count.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);`

Comment: For future readers, this does not apply if you have ImmutableMap.

Comment: What do you mean with auto-boxing ?

Comment: Why doesn't this work? `map.put(key, ++map.get(key))`

Comment: @hackjutsu you need to put the ++ on the right side, not left for this to work (pre vs post action).

Comment: @apadana This should be a pre-action because we increase the value from `map.get(key)` first before we put it back to map.

Comment: @Martin.. map.put(key, map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1)

Comment: How a integer become a string at value part when you write map.get(key) + 1?

Comment: is there a way to simplify it further using lambdas ?

Comment: this assume key exists 
map.getOrDefault() is better alternative

 map.put(num, map.getOrDefault(num, 0) + 1);

Comment: how to update the hash map with Kotlin scoped functions?

Answer (score 149):

### Java 8 way:

You can use `computeIfPresent` method and supply it a mapping function, which will be called to compute a new value based on existing one.

For example,

```
Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<>();
words.put("hello", 3);
words.put("world", 4);
words.computeIfPresent("hello", (k, v) -> v + 1);
System.out.println(words.get("hello"));
```

Alternatevely, you could use `merge` method, where 1 is the default value and function increments existing value by 1:

```
words.merge("hello", 1, Integer::sum);
```

In addition, there is a bunch of other useful methods, such as `putIfAbsent`, `getOrDefault`, `forEach`, etc.

Comment: I just tested your solutions. The second one, the one with method reference, works. The first one, the lambda expression one, is not working consistently when any value of your map is `null` (say `words.put("hello", null);`), the result is still `null` not `1` as I would expect.

Comment: From Javadoc: "If the value for the specified key is present and non-null, attempts to compute a new mapping". You can use `compute()` instead, it will handle `null` values as well.

Comment: I want to increment my value by 1. `.merge` is my solution with `Integer::sum`.

Answer (score 79):

The simplified **Java 8** way:

```
map.put(key, map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
```

This uses the method of HashMap that retrieves the value for a key, but if the key can't be retrieved it returns the specified default value (in this case a '0').

This is supported within core Java: [HashMap<K,V> getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)

Comment: This is one is better in case you are on java 1.8

Answer (score 54):

```
hashmap.put(key, hashmap.get(key) + 1);
```

The method `put` will *replace* the value of an existing key and will create it if doesn't exist.

Comment: No, it doesn't create, it gives `nullPointer Exception`.

Comment: The code is a correct answer for the given question, but was posted a year after the exact same code was posted in the accepted answer. The thing that differentiates this answer is stating put can create a new entry, which it can, but not in this example. If you are using hashmap.get(key) for a non-existent key/value you'll get null and when you attempt to increment, as @smttsp says it will NPE. -1

Comment: This answer is wrong. NullPointerException for non-existing keys

Comment: @smttp NullpointterException only if you didn't initialize the value ( as you know you cannot increment null )

Comment: Duplication and incorrect explanation... _and will create it if doesn't exist_ You can't do `null + 1` since this will try to unboxe the `null` into an integer to do the increment.

Answer (score 30):

Replace `Integer` by [`AtomicInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and call one of the `incrementAndGet`/`getAndIncrement` methods on it.

An alternative is to wrap an `int` in your own `MutableInteger` class which has an `increment()` method, you only have a threadsafety concern to solve yet.

Comment: AtomicInteger is a Mutable Integer but builtin.  I seriously doubt writing your own MutableInteger is a better idea.

Comment: Custom `MutableInteger` is better, as `AtomicInteger` uses `volatile`, which has overhead. I'd use `int[1]` instead of `MutableInteger`.

Comment: @Oliv: not concurrent.

Comment: @BalusC but still, volatile write is more expensive. It invalidates caches. If it were no difference, all variables would be volatile.

Comment: @Oliv: question explicitly mentions hashcode collision, so concurrency is important for OP.

Comment: @BalusC hashcode collision is not about concurrency at all. Concurrency is about accessing the value from multiple threads, which is not required here.

Answer (score 21):

One line solution:

```
map.put(key, map.containsKey(key) ? map.get(key) + 1 : 1);
```

Comment: That doesn't add anything new to the existing answers, does it?

Comment: Yes, It does. It correct marked answer will throw a NullPointerException if key does not exists. This solution will work fine.

Answer (score 19):

@Matthew's solution is the simplest and will perform well enough in most cases.

If you need high performance, AtomicInteger is a better solution ala @BalusC.

However, a faster solution (provided thread safety is not an issue) is to use [TObjectIntHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TObjectIntHashMap.html) which provides a increment(key) method and uses primitives and less objects than creating AtomicIntegers. e.g.

```
TObjectIntHashMap<String> map = new TObjectIntHashMap<String>()
map.increment("aaa");
```

Answer (score 14):

You can increment like below but you need to check for existence so that a NullPointerException is not thrown

```
if(!map.containsKey(key)) {
 p.put(key,1);
}
else {
 p.put(key, map.getKey()+1);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Does the hash exist (with 0 as the value) or is it "put" to the map on the first increment? If it is "put" on the first increment, the code should look like:

```
if (hashmap.containsKey(key)) {
    hashmap.put(key, hashmap.get(key)+1);
} else { 
    hashmap.put(key,1);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It may be little late but here are my two cents.

If you are using Java 8 then you can make use of [computeIfPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method. If the value for the specified key is present and non-null then it attempts to compute a new mapping given the key and its current mapped value.

```
final Map<String,Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("A",0);
map1.put("B",0);
map1.computeIfPresent("B",(k,v)->v+1);  //[A=0, B=1]
```

We can also make use of another method [putIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) to put a key. If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null) then this method associates it with the given value and returns null, else returns the current value.

In case the map is shared across threads then we can make use of `ConcurrentHashMap` and [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). From the doc:

> An `AtomicInteger` is an int value that may be updated atomically.  An
>   AtomicInteger is used in applications such as atomically incremented
>   counters, and cannot be used as a replacement for an Integer. However,
>   this class does extend Number to allow uniform access by tools and
>   utilities that deal with numerically-based classes.

We can use them as shown:

```
final Map<String,AtomicInteger> map2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map2.putIfAbsent("A",new AtomicInteger(0));
map2.putIfAbsent("B",new AtomicInteger(0)); //[A=0, B=0]
map2.get("B").incrementAndGet();    //[A=0, B=1]
```

One point to observe is we are invoking `get` to get the value for key `B` and then invoking `incrementAndGet()` on its value which is of course `AtomicInteger`. We can optimize it as the method `putIfAbsent` returns the value for the key if already present:

```
map2.putIfAbsent("B",new AtomicInteger(0)).incrementAndGet();//[A=0, B=2]
```

On a side note if we plan to use [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) then as per documentation under high contention expected throughput of [LongAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html) is significantly higher, at the expense of higher space consumption. Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691083/how-longadder-performs-better-than-atomiclong).

Answer (score 6):

The cleaner solution without NullPointerException is:

```
map.replace(key, map.get(key) + 1);
```

Comment: if key doesn't exist then map.get(key) will throw NPE

Comment: Yes that is true

Answer (score 5):

Since I can't comment to a few answers due to less reputation, I will post a solution which I applied.

```
for(String key : someArray)
{
   if(hashMap.containsKey(key)//will check if a particular key exist or not 
   {
      hashMap.put(hashMap.get(key),value+1);// increment the value by 1 to an already existing key
   }
   else
   {
      hashMap.put(key,value);// make a new entry into the hashmap
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer i = map.get(key);
if(i == null)
   i = (aValue)
map.put(key, i + 1);
```

or

```
Integer i = map.get(key);
map.put(key, i == null ? newValue : i + 1);
```

Integer is Primitive data types http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/java-data.html, so you need to take it out, make some process, then put it back. if you have a value which is not Primitive data types, you only need to take it out, process it, no need to put it back into the hashmap.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Correction:  Integer class is not a Primitive data type, rather it is a wrapper class for the primitive type int. Moreover, thanks to autoboxing post-Java8, there is already an accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158002/10993032

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop to increment the index:

```
for (int i =0; i<5; i++){
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("beer", 100);

    int beer = map.get("beer")+i;
    System.out.println("beer " + beer);
    System.out ....

}
```

Comment: That would just overwrite the Map on each iteration. See Matthew's answer for the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are misleading answers to this question here that imply Hashtable put method will replace the existing value if the key exists, this is not true for Hashtable but rather for HashMap. See Javadoc for HashMap http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29

Answer (score 1):

Use Java8 built in fuction 'computeIfPresent'

Example:

```
public class ExampleToUpdateMapValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> bookAuthors = new TreeMap<>();
        bookAuthors.put("Genesis","Moses");
        bookAuthors.put("Joshua","Joshua");
        bookAuthors.put("Judges","Samuel");

        System.out.println("---------------------Before----------------------");
        bookAuthors.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        // To update the existing value using Java 8
        bookAuthors.computeIfPresent("Judges", (k,v) -> v = "Samuel/Nathan/Gad");

        System.out.println("---------------------After----------------------");
        bookAuthors.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
HashMap hm=new HashMap<String ,Double >();
```

NOTE:

```
String->give the new value; //THIS IS THE KEY
else
Double->pass new value; //THIS IS THE VALUE
```

You can change either the key or the value in your hashmap, but you can't change both at the same time.