# How can I change the value of a key in a hash map?

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value

I have created a hash map that the users input the key and the value. I want to be able to change the value of the hash map if a specific key is entered. I tried the `setValue` method but got nothing. The value and the key are both strings. What method would I use to change this?

Comment: Just `put` a new value for the same key.

Answer (score 25):

Just use `Map#put` using the current *old* key and the new value:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("user", "Luiggi Mendoza");
System.out.println(map);
//replacing the old value
map.put("user", "Oli Charlesworth");
System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{user=Luiggi Mendoza}
{user=Oli Charlesworth}
```

Comment: It's still not giving me the correct output. Maybe its the contain method I am using.

Comment: Here is my code:  if (item.contains("music"))
            {
             double newprice = Double.parseDouble(price);
             newprice = newprice *1.10;
             
             String newprice2 = String.valueOf(newprice);
             cart.put(item, newprice2);
            }

Comment: You're using contains for "music" key but the replace uses `item` variable as key, which may not be the same value. Provide a code to replicate your specific problem.

Comment: @pgray10 please provide the `equals` and `hashCode` implementation for your the class of your `item` variable as well.

Comment: this link might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/18153757/1533783