# Update the value of specified key in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following HashMap where the key is String and value is represented by a HashMap.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>  outerMap = new  HashMap<String,HashMap<String, Integer>();
HashMap<String, Integer> innerMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
innerMap.put("Amount", 2000);
outerMap.put("TutionFee", innerMap);
```

Now I want to  update the value of `Amount` key. How can I update the value of `Amount` key?

Comment: Check [How to update a value, given a key in a java hashmap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157972/how-to-update-a-value-given-a-key-in-a-java-hashmap)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
outerMap.get("TutionFee").put("Amount", newValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose new value to update is 1000, then `outerMap.get("TutionFee").put("Amount", 1000);`