# How to count the number of each word in string

Tags: java

I am trying to find the number of occurrences of each word in string.

For example `Sentence=" My home, is my home"`. The answer is "my"=2; "home"=2; "is"=1

Here is my code:

```
int count;
count = 0;
String text[] = new String[100];
String Temp[] = new String[100];
text = Text.getText().split("\\W");
Temp = Text.getText().split("\\W");
for (int j = 0;  j < text.length; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {

        if (text[j].equals(Temp[i])) {
            count += 1;
            System.out.println(text[i] + "-" + count);
        }
    }
}
```

Input: `me.me.me.me`
Output:

```
me-1
me-2
me-3
me-4
me-5
me-6
me-7
me-8
me-9
me-10
me-11
me-12
me-13
me-14
me-15
me-16
```

Comment: You can do it easily using a HashMap. Take a look at my answer. And don't forget to mark it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the hollow tick next to the answer. ;-)

Comment: This place is not for asking homework questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/HashMap.html), `HashMap<String, Integer>` for doing this.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
String sentence = "My home, is my home".toLowerCase();

for(String word : sentence.split("\\W")) {
    if(word.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }
    if(map.containsKey(word)) {
        map.put(word, map.get(word)+1);
    }
    else {
        map.put(word, 1);
    }
}

for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Output:

```
is: 1
my: 2
home: 2
```

Take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157972/how-to-update-a-value-given-a-key-in-a-java-hashmap). There you will see something very similar to what you've asked being answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the String using split()

```
String[] s;
s = split("."); //Will split a sentence into an array
```

So if the input is me.me.me.me. S[0] = "me", S[1] = "me" etc.

Then you just find the length of the array to see how many words were in the original String.
So.....

```
count = s.length;
System.out.println(count);
```

The question you are asking is very convoluted, but I assume you were trying to "count the number of words in a string.
I can't post a comment yet because my rep is beginning. But, you already have a working solution... This is not the place to be posting the solution to your own answers to show it off?

Comment: I need to count number of each word in sentence. For example Sentence=" My home, is my home". The answer is "my"=2; "home"=2; "is"=1;