# java- hashmap one key and multiple values alternative to storing the value part in a List

Tags: java, hashmap

Usually when you have multiple values for the same key in hash map the answers I have found would use a `List` or  `ArrayList` to store the value part. For example:

```
Map<Object,ArrayList<Object>> multiMap = new HashMap<Object,ArrayList<Object>>();
```

I was wondering it was possible to keep the normal definition of hashmap and append any new values to the old value (comma separated). Something like this:

```
Map<String, String> memOf = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> subOrg = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> email = new HashMap<String, String>();

 String line="";
    String source="";
    String sub="";
    String obj="";
    String hashKey="";
    String hashVal="";


    for (Text value : values){ //start iterate over values 
        line=value.toString();
        String[] parts=line.trim().split(",");



    source=parts[0].trim();
    sub=parts[1].trim();
    obj=parts[2].trim();
    hashKey=sub;



    if (source.equals("memberOf")){
        hashVal=memOf.get(hashKey);
        if (hashVal!=null){
        hashVal=hashVal+","+obj;
        memOf.put(hashKey, hashVal);
        } 
    }
```

}

The previous code is to populate the hashmaps and **next to read individual values use `split(",")`and store them in a String array**. something like:

```
for (String key1 : memOf.keySet()) {             
    x=key1;
    String[] y=memOf.get(x).toString().split(",");

    int numberOfItems = y.length;
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfItems; i++){  
    System.out.println(y[i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What about if you want to store a value containing a comma?

Comment: And how could this be a better idea than using a list as value. Now you need to split every time you want to get or remove an element, and you have to deal with values containing commas somehow. It's more cumbersome to use, and less efficient. There is really no reason to do that.

Comment: It seems you've already done it. What is preventing you here?

Comment: I think OP asks for an existing way to do so, something like `map.addValueToExisting(value);`. He is doing it in a non-efficient manner, and asks if it is possible to do so otherwise.

Comment: Perhaps look into multimaps, e.g. [Guava's](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: If you look that way, then you dont need Map also. You can do it in String array and have first value as key and remaining as values.

Comment: I see literally no reason why you would do this. Use a `Map<K, List<V>>` and the new `Map.computeIfAbsent` method.

Comment: If @Yassine is correct, then you are looking for `Map.merge`.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering it was possible to keep the normal definition of hashmap and append any new values to the old value (comma separated).

You already did it. In an inefficient manner, but you did it.

As pointed out by [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) in the comments, you may look for implementations like Guava's [MultiMap](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/guava/guava_multimap.htm) which allows to map a single key to multiple values.

Aside from that, the [official Map documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) **does not** report such capabilities of adding one value to another, only replacing it. In the case of Integers, you can [increment them pretty easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157972/how-to-update-a-value-given-a-key-in-a-java-hashmap?rq=1), but for the rest you'll have to either do it yourself or find a more efficient way (e.g. an `ArrayList`).

Comment: I dont think I have another choice, if so , how would it be implemented  in an arrayList?

Comment: Note that I need to append values to multiple array Lists as they values appear.