# Update a hashmap value, given a key with getOrDefault

Tags: java-8, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` :

```
HashMap<string, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<>();
```

where I want to increase the HashMap value. In order to avoid the `nullPointer Exception` if the key doesn't exist, I check it! Let's say the data are:

```
//201803271 - 1000
//201803271 - 1000
//201803272 - 1000

//inside a loop i read the data...
  if (hmap.get("201803271") != null) {
      hmap.put("201803271", hmap.get("201803271") + 1000);
  }else{
      hmap.put("201803271", 1000);
  }
//end of loop
```

which works as I get:

```
201803271 - 2000
201803272 - 1000
```

But, I read this question [How to update a value, given a key in a java hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157972/how-to-update-a-value-given-a-key-in-a-java-hashmap) and there is a solution to use the Java 8 method `getOrDefault`. I tried it

```
hmap.put("201803271", count.getOrDefault("201803271", 1000) + 1000)
```

However, with this solution I get wrong results...

```
201803271 - 3000
201803272 - 2000
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 8 introduced [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method to `Map` interface just for this type of problem:

```
hmap.merge("201803271", 1000, Integer::sum);
```

It means "put 1000 for this key but if this key already has a value add 1000 to it".

The reason your solution wasn't working is that you were getting 1000 by default and then adding 1000 to it.  To do this correctly with `getOrDefault`, you would want to replace 1000 with 0 in `getOrDefault`. `hmap.put("201803271", count.getOrDefault("201803271", 0) + 1000))`

Answer (score 5):

You could do it like this:

```
map.put(key, map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + inc);
```

or

```
map.compute(key, (k, v) -> v == null ? inc : v + inc);
```