# Java adjusting nested Hashmap value

Tags: java, hashmap

I was trying to use ideas given here to adjust a nested hashmap but my solution does not work: [How to update a value, given a key in a java hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157972/how-to-update-a-value-given-a-key-in-a-java-hashmap). My nested hashmap is `shoppingLists`. It contains an outer hashmap of shopping list `listID` as key and a hashmap of items as values. The items hashmap contains `itemName` as key and the amount of the item as the value. The `adjustItemAmount` attempts to adjust the amount of an item by a given amount `x`.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> shoppingLists = new HashMap<>();

public void adjustItemAmount(String itemName, int x, String listID) {
  int current_amount = shoppingLists.get(listID).get(itemName);
  HashMap<String, Integer> items = shoppingLists.get(listID);
  HashMap updatedItems = items.put(itemName, items.get(itemName) + x);
  shoppingLists.put(listID, updatedItems);
}
```

The line `HashMap updatedItems = items.put(itemName,items.get(itemName)+x);` states that Java expects a hashmap but gets an integer. I do not see how that is the case.

Comment: So, what's the problem with this code?

Comment: Edited the question to indicate the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "states that Java expects a hashmap but gets an integer."? If you're getting an exception, post the complete details: exception type, message and stack trace. Also, please, create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the moment we can't execute your code without making assumptions about your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put in HashMap returns the Value object, in this case Integer. You are trying to assign this Integer to HashMap. Remove the assignment, your code will work. Replace

```
public void  adjustItemAmount (String itemName, int x,String listID){
            int current_amount = shoppingLists.get(listID).get(itemName);
            HashMap <String,Integer> items = shoppingLists.get(listID);
            items.put(itemName,items.get(itemName)+x);
            shoppingLists.put(listID,items);    
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

HashMap's put method does not return a HashMap. It returns the value. Hence this line is incorrect:

```
    HashMap updatedItems= items.put(itemName,items.get(itemName)+x);
```

The return type would be Integer because items map is of `<String, Integer>` type.

Answer (score 2):

You write

```
HashMap updatedItems= items.put(itemName,items.get(itemName)+x);
```

However the put method returns the previous value of the key, which was updated, or null if there was no value, not the HashMap. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-

Change the line to

```
Integer addedValue = items.put(itemName,items.get(itemName)+x);
```

or just

```
items.put(itemName,items.get(itemName)+x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer the documentation for `put` -

> Returns : the previous value associated with key, or null if there was
>   no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map
>   previously associated null with key, if the implementation supports
>   null values.)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)

So, this

`HashMap updatedItems= items.put(itemName,items.get(itemName)+x);`

will fail the compilation and can not return a `HashMap` but it returns an `Integer`

Instead, it should be -

`Integer updatedItems= items.put(itemName,items.get(itemName)+x);`