# Java: Only Print Unique Characters in a String

Tags: java

I am writing a program to display only the unique characters in a string which is entered by the user through a `Scanner`.

For example, if the user enters the following line

```
eleven seven
```

Then my expected output will be

```
lvn svn
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class unique_element {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        char value = 0;

        String str1[] = str.split(" ");

        for (int k=0;k<str1.length;k++){
            char string[] = str1[k].toLowerCase().toCharArray();

            String temp = "";
            for(int i=0;i<string.length;i++){
                char current = string[i];
                if(temp.indexOf(current)<0){
                    temp = temp + current;
                }else{
                    temp = temp.replace(String.valueOf(current), "");
                }
            }
            System.out.print(temp+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

And here's sample output with the above code:

```
Eleven seven
lven svn
```

Comment: You mean you want to display characters **which only occur once**? Because L V E and N are the unique characters of the word 'eleven'.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question and to describe your problem.

Comment: create a `Map<Character, Integer> characterToOccurences`, then iterate over it and print the letter if the `value == 1`

Comment: yes I want output :-  lvn svn

Comment: but without map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my question correct answer I got:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class unique_element {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        char value = 0;

        String str1[] = str.split(" ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str1));

        for (int k=0;k<str1.length;k++){

            char string[] = str1[k].toLowerCase().toCharArray();

            for (int i=0;i<string.length;i++){
                int count=0;
                for (int j=0;j<string.length;j++){
                    if(i!=j){
                        if(string[i]==string[j]){
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(count==0){
                    System.out.print(string[i]);
                }
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
            
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a hash map and add every char in your string.
Then increment the int value when the same char comes.

```
map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
```

should work.

Also check this: [How to update a value, given a key in a hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157972/how-to-update-a-value-given-a-key-in-a-hashmap)

Answer (score 0):

Using java8 [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [the collectors framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

```
 String result=Arrays.stream("Eleven seven".toCharArray())
                     .distinct()
                     .map(ch->ch+"")
                     .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapt your solution a little bit. I changed the [string concatenation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-strings-concatenation) a bit, so that a new string does not have to be created with every iteration. At the end I made the solution with [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) and [`lastIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-). But I guess that there is a more efficient solution. This is the code:

```java
String content = "Eleven seven";

String[] splittedContent = content.toLowerCase().split(" ");

for (String word: splittedContent) {
    char[] splittedWord = word.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (char element: splittedWord) {
        int index = word.indexOf(Character.toString(element));
        int lastIndex = word.lastIndexOf(Character.toString(element));

        // only true if the character occurs once in the word
        if (index == lastIndex) {
            builder.append(element);
        }
    }

    System.out.print(builder.toString() + " ");
}
```

Otherwise there is another solution with the Java Stream API. I use the [`groupingBy`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector) method to create the map with single characters and their counting. At the end I filter the unique single characters and create a string. The solution is similar to the proposal of @Bora Çolakoğlu:

```java
for (String s: content.toLowerCase().split(" ")) {
    // creating the map with single characters and their counting
    Map<String, Long> frequentChars = s.chars()
        .mapToObj(Character::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    // filter unique single characters and join to string
    String unique = frequentChars.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(v -> v.getValue() == 1L)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

    System.out.println(unique);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 we can do something like this

```
private void removeduplicatecharactersfromstring() {
    String myString = "aabcd eeffff ghjkjkl";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println(myString);
    Arrays.asList(myString.split(" "))
            .forEach(s -> {
                builder.append(Stream.of(s.split(""))
                        .distinct().collect(Collectors.joining()).concat(" "));
            });
    System.out.println(builder); // abcd ef ghjkl
}
```