# Big Decimal in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, oop, bigdecimal

As trainee in Java I need to find how to reduce the value of a BigDecimal variable with the value of a Map, thats also BigDecimal.. OK, for example:
I have a restaurant with wareHose where I save my productAvailabilities and a menuMap, where I create my products, SO: when I have an order (Pizza), I have to reduce the available quantity from the wareHouse, with the quantities I need for create my order.
Every single Pizza has its map : Map<Product.Type, Quantity> pizza

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a value, given a key in a hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157972/how-to-update-a-value-given-a-key-in-a-hashmap)

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update value of `Quantity`, then you can use `put` method

```
pizza.put(key, val);
```

to add a new key/value pair or overwrite an existing key's value.

Answer (score 1):

```java
class Recipe:
    pizza.put(Product.Type.CHEDDAR, new Quantity(BigDecimal.valueOf(40), Quantity.Unit.G));
        pizza.put(Product.Type.ONION, new Quantity(BigDecimal.valueOf(20), Quantity.Unit.G));
        pizzaList.add(new Pizza(Pizza.PizzaType.CLASSIC, Pizza.PizzaSize.LARGE, pizza));

class WareHouse :

     foodQuantities.put(Product.Type.ONION, new Product(Product.Type.ONION, BigDecimal.valueOf(5)));
        foodQuantities.put(Product.Type.CHEDDAR, new Product(Product.Type.CHEDDAR, BigDecimal.valueOf(5)));

class Chef:
//The chef cooks, so he reduce the available quantity from ware house by using the neededIngredients from the Recipe.

avilableProducts.computeIfPresent(Product.Type.TOMATO, (k, v) -> v - 0.100);
            avilableProducts.computeIfPresent(Product.Type.CUCUMBER, (k, v) -> v - 0.100);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).